# Live-Updating Review Counts

Tags: feature-request, review, notifications

As an avid reviewer (but also internet user at large), I typically have a tab open for a site's review queue, but it's mildly annoying to have to constantly go over to that tab and constantly <kbd>F5</kbd> to check if there are any new review items.

Ideally, I'd like to have the `/review` page auto-refresh counts, and display the new values live as they come in. For example, a new Suggested Edit is available, the number for Suggested Edits should instantly jump up.

In the same vein, if I'm not on the Review tab, a little notification counter, like on Chat, should be present, counting up for each new review item added since I've last visited the tab:

[image: (1) Review - Ask Ubuntu]

Again, like chat, this number should dismiss when I visit the tab and check on what's going on. Perhaps, if at all possible, a desktop notification could also come up on a new Review item, provided I've enabled that feature.

While this isn't a big (or really, important) change, it would still be a nice quality-of-life improvement and let frequent reviewers respond more quickly to things happening in the queues.

Answer (score 1):

There are some user scripts available on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) which do exactly this.

I'm using [Review Stalker Reloaded](https://stackapps.com/q/6869/34061) by Nathan Tuggy myself.

> Its purpose is to be a one-stop pinned tab, always checking for review opportunities as aggressively as is useful between multiple sites you configure.